# Hash and upload an image file at the same time using php

Tags: php, hash

I am trying to upload an image to a server using PHP and calculate the hash of the same image using md5_file. but somehow it is not referring to the directory either and not calculating the hash of the image.

Code:-

```
<html><body style="background-color:powderblue;">
<?php

session_start(); //declare you are starting a session





if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    include'connect.php';

    $fname = $_POST['fi'];
    $filename = $_FILES['fileupload']['name'];
    $filetmp = $_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['fileupload']['size'];
    $file_basename = basename($_FILES['fileupload']['name']);
    $dir = "upload/";
    $final_dir = $dir.$file_basename;
    $hash = md5_file($final_dir);   
    $_SESSION['hash'] =$hash;


    $upload = move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$final_dir);
}




/* image_name= "$file_basename";
    image_path ="$final_dir";

*/

    /*Database Query*/**strong text**

        if($filesize > 1024000){
            echo("Greater then expected");
            }










if($selected){

    echo nl2br("Operation successful\n");
    echo nl2br("URL Record successfully\n");
    echo nl2br("$fname \n \n");

    }
else{
    echo("No No No ...");

}

?>
```

Comment: Tried debugging your code? And it's `md5` not `md5_file` except that's a custom written function

Comment: Found the mistake. Thank you . just wanted to ask if there is any way I can hash the file and its time stamp again? hash(hash (image) . timestamp) in php ?

Comment: Also @Akintunde md5_file is for hashing a file https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/func_string_md5_file.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hash the temporary file before moving it to the final destination.

```
$hash = md5_file($filetmp);
...
$upload = move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$final_dir);
```